# CS50 Badge count not updated on main Stack Exchange Network site

Tags: bug, badges, stackexchange.com, network-profile

On [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/users/29488/rob?tab=badges), Harvard's ["Introduction to Computer Science"](https://pll.harvard.edu/course/cs50-introduction-computer-science?delta=0), free online course I have 4 badges:

> [image]

On our [Stack Exchange Network](https://stackexchange.com/users/4485506/rob?tab=accounts) site it says that I have **0** badges:

> [image]